# I used PinchGesture In my ImageView.This code run perfectly ,now I like to stop ZoomOut at some size, what should i do?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimageview, uigesturerecognizer

I used `PinchGesture` In my `ImageView`.This code run perfectly ,now I like to stop `ZoomOut` at some size, what should i do ?

```
UIPanGestureRecognizer *panGesture=[[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePan:)];
    panGesture.delegate=self;
    [overlayimageView addGestureRecognizer:panGesture];


- (void)handlePinch:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{

    recognizer.view.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(recognizer.view.transform, recognizer.scale, recognizer.scale);
    recognizer.scale = 1;
}
```

[image: here Starting image]

[image: but i does not want to ZoomOut More than 200*200]

Answer (score 1):

```
CGFloat scale = 1.0 - (ImageLastScale - pinchscale);
CGRect bounds = [(UIPinchGestureRecognizer*)sender view].bounds;
scale = MIN(scale, maximumHeight / CGRectGetHeight(bounds));//define maximumHeight and minimumHeight for zoom level
scale = MAX(scale, minimumHeight / CGRectGetHeight(bounds));
```

with Method i use this like bellow.. Define `lastScale` variable as `Float` object in .h file

```
-(void)scale:(id)sender {

    if([(UIPinchGestureRecognizer*)sender state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        lastScale = 1.0;
        return;
    }

    CGFloat pinchscale = [(UIPinchGestureRecognizer*)sender scale];
    CGFloat scale = 1.0 - (lastScale - pinchscale);
    CGAffineTransform currentTransform = [(UIPinchGestureRecognizer*)sender view].transform;
    CGAffineTransform holderTransform = holderView.transform;
    CGAffineTransform newTransform = CGAffineTransformScale(currentTransform, scale, scale);
    [[(UIPinchGestureRecognizer*)sender view] setTransform:newTransform];

    CGFloat scale = 1.0 - (lastScale - pinchscale);
    CGRect bounds = [(UIPinchGestureRecognizer*)sender view].bounds;
    scale = MIN(scale, maximumHeight / CGRectGetHeight(bounds));
    scale = MAX(scale, minimumHeight / CGRectGetHeight(bounds));

    lastScale = [(UIPinchGestureRecognizer*)sender scale];
}
```

**Updated**

```
    UIPinchGestureRecognizer *pinchGesture=[[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(scale:)];
    pinchGesture.delegate=self;
    [overlayimageView addGestureRecognizer:pinchGesture];
```

i hope this answer is helpful to you..

Comment: with selector like you define in UIPanGesture @selector(handlePan:) same like in UIPinchGesture define @selector(scale:)..

Comment: this code not working properly, Because 'scale' variable define in 2 times. 
1st:- CGFloat scale = 1.0 - (lastScale - pinchscale);

2nd:- CGFloat scale = 1.0 - (lastScale - pinchscale);

Comment: whats the problem here?? mate

Comment: The images are still ZoomIN And ZoomOut at any size, I want to Stop ZoomOut at 300*300. but this code not working.
so what is the solution? can you help me.?

Comment: yes mate ..  why not?? this code work fine but something going wrong.. i'll post Update answer after some time mate..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18298/discussion-between-vishal-khatri-and-paras-joshi)